# [JAVA][Parse Html] How to simulate pressing the button

Tags: java, android

I parse website via HttpURLConnection. I need to simulate pressing the button and get a response code from website.

Following is response from website

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tab"  onClick="doCalculate('130');">Calculate</a>
```

How to simulate doing "doCalculate" then get a response?

Comment: You realise that by just downloading the HTML content from the URL using HttpURLConnection you don't have all the bells and whistles a browser has, when opens a page, do you? You have to use more sophisticated tools to be able to run the Javascript too on the page, like HtmlUnit (but I'm not sure it is available/runs correctly on Android too)

Comment: Not sure about the android world either but here is a first impression where id start (never did something like this): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086996/executing-javascript-in-java-opening-a-url-and-getting-links defently need to try this as well