# Downloading HTML instead of File

Tags: java, html, file, url, download

I'm using Java code to download a file from the Internet and save it to some directory.

However, the code downloads the `HTML` source code of the page instead of the file contents.

The code below illustrates the problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

public class JavaFileDownloadTest
{
    public static void download(String remoteURL, String targetFilePath)
            throws IOException
    {
        URL downloadableFile = new URL(remoteURL);
        ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(downloadableFile.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath);
        fileOutputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException
    {
        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        String fileName = "Test.txt";
        String targetFilePath = userHome + File.separator + "Downloads" + File.separator + fileName;
        download("http://bullywiiplaza.cuccfree.com/" + fileName, targetFilePath);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(targetFilePath));
    }
}
```

The file located [here](http://bullywiiplaza.cuccfree.com/Test.txt) contains the text

```
Hello StackOverflow!
```

However, when downloaded using the above code, I'm getting the `HTML` source code as file content instead:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("ae71113e4baf38cee1c1aacf0ae66c00");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://bullywiiplaza.cuccfree.com/Test.txt?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Why is this and how do I fix it? I already tried various libraries and methods for downloading files but all of them yielded this same "faulty" result.

Comment: Choose a better file host. The one you're using refuses to serve the file until some cookie has been set (probably for analytics). What you're seeing is code they deliver to browsers who don't have the cookie yet. Notice if you go to that link in a private browser it redirects (using that code you see) and adds `?ckattempt=1` to the end.

Comment: @Matt:
I did notice that the browser redirected but I didn't know what to do with it to programmatically download the file

Comment: The solution is: choose a better file host. The one you've chosen requires analytics tracking before it will deliver the file. Programmatically downloading the file means that Java is the "browser" in your case and it A) doesn't have the cookies your browser has and B) can't execute JavaScript to create that cookie. Only a browser can satisfy that file host's requirements. They are actively blocking cURL (by `403`ing it) and you have to download dependencies (`aes.js`) before you can even execute their analytics script. Try a better host like GitHub Pages or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the website hoster to [this one](http://www.freewebhostingarea.com/) and now the code from above works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the target url executes some javascript to provide the file. This script has to be interpreted (and executed) by some javascript engine.

So you need either some resolution to get the real file url (and not just the javascript) or integrate some javascript engine to execute the script code and get the result.

I think this could help you: [Executing javascript in java - Opening a URL and getting links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086996/executing-javascript-in-java-opening-a-url-and-getting-links)

or better:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/ExecuteJavascriptscriptinafile.htm

Comment: How would you use this to solve the problem of downloading the correct file?

Comment: Perhaps my links were disleading, sorry. I thought a script enigne would work, but this is only for executing script you provide. In this case I think it is very hard achive what you want because your provider blocks the access. See @Matt's comment to your question.

Answer (score -1):

http://bullywiiplaza.cuccfree.com/Test.txt doesn't exist. I think the url should be https://bullywiiplaza.cuccfree.com/Test.txt which exists.

Comment: Sorry, both exist but using `https` throws a `SSLHandshakeException`

Comment: Yes sorry, you are correct. You have aes.js which intercepts the request and put a URL parameter and gets the page. This is not a simple download .