# Simulate JavaScript "window" object when running JS file from Java

Tags: javascript, java, dom, rhino

I'm integrating OpenPay payment gateway to one of our application. When doing testing, It needs something called "deviceDataId" which can be generate using OpenPay JavaScript library (https://github.com/open-pay/openpay-js). This value should be generated in the client's browser.

```
var deviceDataId = OpenPay.deviceData.setup("formId");
```

But I need to run this within my Java application for testing my implementation. So I have run this Js file from my Java Application using following code.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(JsTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("openpay-data.v1.js").getFile())));
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
inv.invokeFunction("OpenPay.deviceData.setup");
```

When I run this code, It will gave me following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#698) in <Unknown source> at line number 698
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(RhinoScriptEngine.java:110)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:232)
    at com.chathura.JsTest.main(JsTest.java:13)
```

I have search here for similar errors and found that the error comes because there is no "document" object when running it from the server side.

[Executing javascript in java - Opening a URL and getting links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086996/executing-javascript-in-java-opening-a-url-and-getting-links)

So rather than edit and re write this JS library to remove all client side dependencies, is there any way to simulate that "document" object when it runs on a server? May be a code block that I can include on top of that JS file?

Comment: There are mock frameworks available for rhino but they all see very old. https://johnresig.com/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/